# GPT disk not recognized by firmware

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios, uefi

My motherboard is BIOSTAR H81MHv3, its BIOS/UEFI/Firmware/Whatever is Aptio Setup Utility Version 2.15.1231 Copyright (C) 2012 American Megatrends, Inc.

I have four disks, all Seagate Hard Disk Drives:

```
Size    Model               Real Size
0.5TB   ST500DM002-1ER14    466GiB
1TB     ST1000DM010-2EP1    932GiB
2TB     ST2000LM007-1R81    1863GiB
4TB     ST4000VX005-2LY1    3726GiB
```

The last disk is newly bought 2 days ago, I have tested it and found no problems, I bought a HDD for storage capacity and not for speed, as I intend to download many games and SSDs of similar size are way too expensive;

Because the size of the disk is over 2048GiB it can only use GPT partition table, the disk had no partitions and already using GPT when bought, so I created the partitions myself using DiskGenius. I created a 300MiB ESP partition and an 128MiB MSR partition first, I then created an 1TiB NTFS partition and a 2TiB NTFS partition, leaving 653.6GB free.

[image]

I plan to install Windows 10 Pro for Workstations v20H2 to the 1TiB partition and install the games to the 2TiB partition, and install Fedora 33 for Workstations to the free space.

But I have encountered a problem: though the partitions are properly recognized by all Windows software, the disk itself isn't recognized by the firmware, meaning I can't boot from the disk.

***This is the default setting***:

[image]

***Using the default setting the HDD isn't recognized***:

[image]

***I tried to disable CSM and still the disk isn't recognized***:

[image]

I Googled for a solution and found a similar question that isn't helpful: [GPT Partitioned Disk not Recognized by BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1074742/gpt-partitioned-disk-not-recognized-by-bios)

I am able to install Windows to the disk using `dism` without problems, but I can't boot from it.

What else should I try to make the HDD bootable?

Comment: Did you already have an ESP on one of your existing disks?

Comment: @fpmurphy No, all three previous disks are MBR and whole disk is one partition, there are no ESP partitions in these disks and only the 4TB HDD is GPT and I have a 16GB SD card  inserted into a card reader that acts as a flash drive that has GPT scheme and is recognized.

Comment: GPT is not just "for large media". UEFI supports only GPT partitioning scheme. You can never boot from MBR disk with UEFI BIOS. If you wan to boot from some drive it **must** be converted to GPT regardless of its size.

Comment: "all three previous disks are MBR and whole disk is one partition" - This is the reason.  You either have to do all GPT or all MBR.  System disks within Windows have a 2 TB MBR limit.  You have CSM enabled which is the reason Windows currently works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UEFI doesn't boots *from disk*, it boots an *EFI executable* from *EFI system partition* (ESP). ESP is a FAT32 partition with certan type. When OS installs in UEFI mode, it creates an entry in the UEFI boot sequence and configures boot order to use that entry first, an entry specifies a ESP where to find a boot loader and its file name. In other words, you need not to configure BIOS boot sequence after installation, installer does that for you.

Such entries can have arbitrary names. In the UEFI BIOS setup program you see those entries under their names. Particularly, Debian linux uses "debian" as the entry name; Windows uses "Windows Boot Manager".

You see three of these in your boot seqence. That could mean either you have more than one ESP, or you reinstalled Windows three times, and each time it created an entry. This what comment up there means.

Unfortunately, I can't suggest you a tool for Windows to directly view or edit these entries; in Linux I use an `efibootmgr` tool which is the program that creates or removes these entries and sets order.

There also could be a "default executable", which is a `(ESP)\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI`. If you are creating boot removable disk, usually you put your bootloader under that path.